# Vectorising a Matlab double loop involving 3D matrices?

Tags: matlab

Consider the following matrices in Matlab

```
A(:,:,1)=[1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A(:,:,2)=[7 8 9; 10 11 12];
M=size(A,1);
N=size(A,2);
R=size(A,3);
```

I want to create a matrix `B` of dimension `(M*N)x(N-1)xR` such that

-for each `r=1,...,R`,

-for each `m=1,...,M`

-for each `h=1,...,N`

-I take `A(m,h,r)`, sum it with each of the `N-1` remaining elements in `A(m,:,r)`, and fill `B((m-1)*N+h,:,r)`.

In the example above it should be

```
B(:,:,1)=[1+2 1+3;
          2+1 2+3;
          3+1 3+2;
          4+5 4+6;
          5+4 5+6;
          6+4 6+5]

B(:,:,2)=[7+8 7+9;
          8+7 8+9;
          9+7 9+8;
          10+11 10+12;
          11+10 11+12;
          12+10 12+11]
```

---

This code does what I want but it contains a double loop, which for `M,N` large may be slow. Could you help me to vectorize?

```
for m=1:M
    for h=1:N
        B((m-1)*N+h,:,:)= repmat(A(m,h,:),1,N-1)+[A(m,1:h-1,:) A(m,h+1:N,:)]; 
    end
end
```

Comment: How big could your dimensions get?

Comment: `M=400`, `N=20`, `R=200`. Moreover, I have to repeat that double loop around 1,000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how much more efficient it will be, but you could reduce it to a single loop like so:

```
[M, N, R] = size(A);
B = zeros(M*N, N-1, R);
for index = logical(eye(N))
  B(find(index):N:end, :, :) = bsxfun(@plus, A(:, ~index, :), A(:, index, :));
end
```